# Is there any way to test that a mining system is set up correctly (solo mining)?

Tags: testing, getblocktemplate

I am running a full node and have written some mining software to learn more about how bitcoin works. I know that the chances of mining a block are basically zero given my hash rate, but I am curious if my setup valid just in case.

When I call:

```
bitcoin-cli getblocktemplate '{"rules": ["segwit"]}'
```

I get back the json template with the following capabilities and mutable

```
  "capabilities": [
    "proposal"
  ],

  ...

  "mutable": [
    "time",
    "transactions",
    "prevblock"
  ],
```

Given these values for capabilities and mutable will the network allow me to insert my coinbase transaction and submit a block? If I intentionally set the difficulty low and generate a block I get the high-hash response, so as far as I can tell the network is able to decode my block. Just looking for other ways to test and verify the setup.

Comment: Hi CryptoJoe, I think https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17553/5406 may answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Murch for the tip. That is a helpful post. I can see testnet, signet and regtest being very useful for many things. Since I'm able to submit a block and get the high-hash error response I know that the network can decode my blocks. I guess the true test if the main network will accept my block is just to wait and see if I ever successfully mine one.