# Running a local testnet

Tags: testnet, signet

a newbie bitcoin researcher here.

For my first work I need a local bitcoin network on which I have as much control as possible. I have a windows machine.

For example - I need to control the number of nodes, network structure, mining difficulty and preferably any other parameter there is.

I downloaded bitcoin-core, installed it and ran its test mode, but it still asks me to download all blockchain history.
I had in mind a new bitcoin-core blockchain built from scratch, so I can control and understand everything.
Is it even possible, using the bitcoin-core software?
If not, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi michaell_co, you might find this related topic interesting: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17553/5406

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of running testnet you would prefer something like [regtest](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/developer-notes.md#signet-testnet-and-regtest-modes)? In order to do this, you can either run bitcoind like this:
`bitcoind -regtest` or add `regtest=1` in your bitcoin.conf file instead of `testnet=1`. This will allow you to spin up a private blockchain and you will have control over when blocks get mined