# how to run bitcoind without downloading entire bitcoin core for development

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-development

I am a beginner in bitcoin development and want to contribute to some github repos and for that i need the regtest network for bitcoin but to run that i need bitcoind and bitcoin core to be downloaded which are 500+ GB in storage and my device has storage constraints . What should i do ?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you need a synchronized node to development. You can download the software and start it with `-regtest`. Also see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17553/5406

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad  I thought even to run the testnet or regtest i need to download the bitcoin core atleast one time but my misconception got cleared afterwards. I specifically didnt need to use only cli but also other libraries dependent on bitcoin core .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run bitcoind without downloading the entire data on bitcoin core follow

https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line

And follow the

> 2.2: Setting Up a Bitcoin-Core Machine via Other Means

Here use the following method

> Using Other Bitcoin Standup Scripts

Comment: But those are instructions for a more specific use, instead of the most generic way to prune a node, which the question was. You could edit the question in order to explain why did you need to use those specific instructions.