# How can I get signet coins?

Tags: faucets, signet, canonical-question

We had several requests for signet coins in the past week. This question is meant as a lightning rod to answer *how to go about and where to direct a request for signet coins* instead of asking for signet coins here on Bitcoin Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

##### Get Signet coins

Since Signet is centrally controlled, you only option is to get it from a faucet or ask for coins in the `bitcoin-signet` IRC channel. But depending on what is your goal, there are other great alternatives to signet which are easier to mine or test with.

##### Alternative testnets

###### Testnet

Testnet has a special rule, which makes it easy to mine in particular circumstances. If there are no blocks found for more than 20 minutes, the difficulty drops and you can easily mine a testnet block with a normal CPU. Obviously your luck depends on if other powerful miners are mining or not. I use [this primitive bash miner script](https://gist.github.com/DaWe35/51f8441f476b14cd39c638334e5c05b5) to mine and I found [6 blocks](https://mempool.space/testnet/address/2N5fJkfCv4cF6vsa5QQJnsazBKWNXynn9zp) in less than 2.5 months.

###### Regtest

In many cases you don't need to test on a public blockchain, so why not run a local testnet? It works just like the Bitcoin network, but external connections are disabled and the mining difficulty is set to 0. This allows you to mine as many blocks as you want, making testing faster and easier.

Answer (score 1):

Signet coins are worthless. They are used for [testing Bitcoin software](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17553/5406) before deploying it on mainnet and protocol development experiments. The signet may be reset occasionally if any projects start to rely on signet for non-testing use-cases.

You can find faucets for small amounts on

- [signetfaucet.com](https://signetfaucet.com)
- [alt.signetfaucet.com](https://alt.signetfaucet.com/)
- [signet.bublina.eu.org](https://signet.bublina.eu.org)

If you need a larger amount, legitimate developers are encouraged to ask in the *#bitcoin-signet* IRC channel on *Libera.chat*.

Comment: Unfortunately, all three of these faucets appear broken :(

Comment: The first and third work for me right now. The second one does seem to have an issue which I am reporting to the owners.