Can I setup a private testnet full node to reduce the testnet gas?
As the title described, I want to set up a bitcoin private testnet full node, in order to reduce the gas I send the transaction.(the transaction I sent to my node can be mined by my node. But I think it's impossible.)

Bitcoin does not have something called "gas", do you mean fees?

Yes, we can query the fee rate through the mempool, so it's the gas I mean.

Possible duplicate of: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/102885/5406
