Is there a Bitcoin wallet extension like MetaMask for transferring BTC in a DApp? How do developers create DApps on Bitcoin?
I'm developing a decentralized application (DApp) that facilitates Bitcoin transfers between user addresses. In the Ethereum ecosystem, we commonly use MetaMask as a wallet provider, which integrates well with DApps and supports test networks like Sepolia for testing.
For Bitcoin, I'm looking for the following information:
Is there a wallet extension or provider similar to MetaMask that can be used for transferring Bitcoin in a DApp?
Is there an official or commonly used test network for Bitcoin, similar to Sepolia on Ethereum, where I can test BTC transfers without using real Bitcoin?
If there is no equivalent of MetaMask for Bitcoin, how do developers typically create DApps for BTC? What is the process for integrating Bitcoin wallet functionality, and are there any specific tools or libraries that are widely used for this purpose?
Any help or guidance on how to handle these aspects for Bitcoin would be greatly appreciated.

This post is asking a lot of different questions in one, and should probably be split up into multiple topics. But either way, check out https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17553/5406 regarding testing networks, and perhaps take a look at Bitcoin Dev Kit regarding a wallet library. If you prefer a different programming language, there are libraries in lots of different languages, see e.g. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption#Libraries for a list with links.
